# Unable to change class variable

Tags: c++, class, variables, setter

I'm trying to switch between two players in a "Match" class. But I can't figure out why it's not working... Seems like it only change the variable localy inside the switchPlayer() function.

```
int main() {
Game game = Game();
cout << game.getMatch().getCurrentPlayer()->getName() << endl;
game.getMatch().switchPlayer();
cout << game.getMatch().getCurrentPlayer()->getName() << endl;
}

class Match {
    public:
        Match();
        Player* getCurrentPlayer() const;
        void switchPlayer();
    private:
        Player* player1; //White
        Player* player2; //Black
        int currentPlayer;
};

Player* Match::getCurrentPlayer() const{
    switch (currentPlayer)
    {
        case 1:
            return player1;
        case 2:
            return player2;
        default:
            cout << "joueurs qui n'existe pas" << endl;
            return player1;
    }
}
void Match::switchPlayer() {
     cout << currentPlayer << endl;
     currentPlayer = currentPlayer == 1 ? 2 : 1;
     cout << currentPlayer << endl;
}
```

Terminal :
    Marie
    1
    2
    Marie

Comment: I think you sould do `currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == 1 )? 2 : 1;` instead of `currentPlayer = currentPlayer == 1 ? 2 : 1;`

Comment: It works perfectly fine ! Thanks you so much !

Comment: @asmmo I don't think there's any difference between the two. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41bdbbebba67f33f

Comment: _Seems like it only change the variable localy inside the switchPlayer() function._ You can print the value of `currentPlayer` in `getCurrentPlayer()` function to be sure. How is `getMatch()` defined? How have the players been initialized? Please update your question with all the pieces involved to get better responses.